# Configuring TightVNC as Portable RDC over internet without Static IP and without touching router config

Tags: remote-desktop-services, vnc

I am trying to customize TightVNC where i can do the below

1. Use it Portable so that i can host server from any computer
2. Use without Global Static IP ie with basic internet connection
3. Use it without disturbing the router

I have the below for this

1. A dedicated Server hosted.
2. Internet in both Server and Client Computers

Any possibility to do this?

Comment: Set up a vpn on every client computer, or use teamviewer.

Comment: I want an alternative for both the suggestion...Already we are doing both and like to make more friendly solution for our customers...

Comment: Package vncserver+vpnclient into one package.

Comment: Can you explain little more detailed @ipor-sircer

Comment: If your clients are running behind NAT (what I suppose), you have to configure port forwarding, so no way without "disturbing the router"

Comment: My major problem is with having access to the router

Comment: I think your clients using  windows. Create one installation exe, which includes vnc+vpn, and start them both with clicking on one icon. Teamviewer does the same. You have no other choice to reach computers behind nat.